# Dll injection - LoadLibraryA fails

Tags: c++, dll, code-injection

I'm trying to inject a dll into a process. The dll does nothing except return TRUE.

I attached a debugger to the process that I want to inject into and confirmed that `LoadLibraryA` is called correctly but returns NULL.
Now I think that this might have something to do with my dll's dependencies. So I checked them and found out that it requires `vcruntime140.dll`.
The process that I want to inject my dll into does not load that dll.

```
#include "pch.h"

extern "C" int __stdcall APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

```
#include "Source.h"

const char* DllName = "InjectMe.dll";

int main()
{
    DWORD processID = 0;
    printf("Process ID: ");
    scanf_s("%i", &processID);

    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);
    if (handle == nullptr) {
        printf("Process could not be opened.");
        return -1;
    }
    LPVOID memDllName = VirtualAllocEx(handle, nullptr, strlen(DllName) + 1, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    assert(memDllName != nullptr);
    assert(WriteProcessMemory(handle, memDllName, DllName, strlen(DllName) + 1, nullptr));

    LPVOID loadLibraryAddr = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    assert(loadLibraryAddr != nullptr);

    HANDLE thread = CreateRemoteThreadEx(handle, nullptr, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)loadLibraryAddr, memDllName, CREATE_SUSPENDED, nullptr, nullptr);
    assert(thread != nullptr);
    ResumeThread(thread);
    DWORD returnCode = WaitForSingleObject(thread, 5000);
    CloseHandle(thread);
    if (returnCode == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
        printf("DLL was not loaded. Thread timed out.");
        return -1;
    }
    else if (returnCode == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        printf("DLL was successfully injected into the process.");
    }
    CloseHandle(handle);
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add a watch for "@err" so you can see the winapi error code.  With error 126 being the file-not-found error that is the most common failure mode for LoadLibrary.  Practically guaranteed to happen when you use "InjectMe.dll", specify the full path of the file so you don't rely on the injected process' search rules.

Comment: Also check 32-bit vs 64-bit as you can't mix the two.

Comment: @HansPassant your answer was correct. I thought I had read somewhere that passing a relative path would be okay as long as the dll was located with the exe of the injected process. Now seems kind of foolish of me to assume that and far less error prone to simply always pass an absolute path.

Comment: Does my answer need any clarification or improvements to answer your question? If so, please reply and I will do my best to improve it. Accepting an answer indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a full file path not a relative file path when calling LoadLibrary()

```cpp
const char* DllName = "InjectMe.dll";
```

needs to be changed to something like this

```
const char* DllName = "c:\\Users\User\\Desktop\\InjectMe.dll";
```

Also make sure you run as administrator if OpenProcess fails or sometimes you also need to use SeDebugPrivelage

Answer (score -1):

In order to test if it is a pathing issue, try the following. Keep the

```
const char* DllName = "InjectMe.dll";
```

Then put the InjectMe.dll and your .exe in the same directory and try to run your exe. If the dll is loaded successfully, then it is a pathing issue.

To work around that, you can either specify the full path like GuidedHacking said, OR you can put your InjectMe.dll in the same directory as the .vcxproj and .cpp files (not where the .sln file is)